# AGSMapView & Autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout, uistoryboard, esri, esri-arc-engine

I'm sorry if this is a double post, or if I didn't read the documentation properly, but does AGSMapview supports working with Autolayout in iOS6/7 and storyboard? I tried enabling Autolayout only to get the following:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews. AGSMapView's implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super.'
```

If I turn off Autolayout for the entire storyboard, then it works just fine. I don't think it's possible, but if I could turn off Autolayout just for the UIViewController where AGSMapView is, that would work too.

Any thoughts on this is deeply appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's your positioning of the element on the UI? Let the MapView with other objects on the same level may solve the issue.

Would you please check this thread on the forum:
http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/80226-assertion-failure-in-agsmapview-layoutsublayersoflayer

Answer (score 0):

I think as the error states, you need to call: [super layoutSubviews] from the layoutSubviews method of AGSMapview.